# How to build a rails form with a single parameter to flat hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a rails-simpleform that looks like this:

```
=simple_form_for :search, url: search_path(:search), method: :get  do |f|
  = f.input :q
  = f.submit 'Search'
```

When I want to retrieve the input I have to access it with:

`params[:search][:q]`

Is it somehow possible to build the form in a way, that the parameters aren't nested under `params[:search]`? So that I can access them directly through `params[:q]`? I understand that this only makes sense if there is only a single input for a form.

**CONTEXT:**

What I'm trying to do is to allow the user to either search through the search-form described above or through a short-url(`myapp.com/search-text`).

Comment: Did you try form_tag instead of form_for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**form_for** (or **simple_form_for**) creates a form associated to a model object. The params passed to the controller add the model name as a key in the hash (params[:search][... fields_in_the_form ...]).

**form_tag** simply creates a form and it is not associated to any model. It does not add any key to the params hash except for the fields in the form. So this is a usual method to create search forms.

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can use `params[:search]` in the controller.

Finally, to use `myapp.com/search-text` you should use route globing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) defining your route as:

```
get '*search', to: 'static_pages#search'
```

The StaticPagesController#search method will receive params[:search] with anything after myapp.com/. **Note**: this should be your last route, as it matches anything.